# Who is Pete's favourite scientist?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge, history

[Pete](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70853/who-is-petes-favourite-composer) is back.

Pete met his old friend Steve at the hospital at the end of March. They both went to the same history class.

> **Pete**: Hey!
>
> **Steve**: Pete? Pete, is that you?
>
> **Pete**: Yes. How are you? Haven't seen you in ages
>
> **Steve**: I am fine. What about you?

The conversation went on for a while. They talked about a lot of things: how they both nailed that one history test without learning anything, how they went to France together for a summer, how they pranked their teacher, and which topic in their class they liked the most. They even both had a favourite scientist. For Steve it was Nikola Tesla.

**Who is Pete's favourite scientist?**

---

Since I'm not a native speaker it would be nice if you could help me to fix the grammar in this riddle. Please do not change the conversation.

Comment: I'm a native speaker, and the grammar looks fine to me.  I wouldn't have known you weren't a native speaker without you saying so.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain some people have already fixed it :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it

> Rene Descartes

who was

> born in 1596 (the number of words in each line), France, at the end of March

Comment: This is correct, well done

Answer (score 1):

If Steve likes Nikola Tesla, could Pete's favorite scientist be

> Thomas Edison?

It's mentioned they both went to France together,

> Thomas Edison patented many inventions in France.

Both nailed that one history test without learning... how they pranked their teacher

> Edison was known to "program" a telegraph to make auto responses at his job when he was 14. [citation needed]

On a more abstract note:

> There are only two periods in their conversation. I don't think this is an accident. Edison was known for using and improving the telegraph. In fact, he named his children Dot and Dash.

Also:

> Edison and Tesla worked together, though Edison and Tesla did fight.

Comment: Good guess, but this answer would be too obvious ;)