# Who is Pete's favourite actor?

Tags: lateral-thinking, knowledge

Pete loves movies. He always watches trailers of the newest blockbuster on Youtube. Sometimes it is hard for him to decide which movie he should watch next, because work is stressful and most of the time he doesn't find time to enjoy the evening in front of the TV.

Since Pete's birthday is coming closer,  his co-workers (who know that Pete loves movies) decide they want to gift him an autograph of his favourite actor. Unfortunately no one knows who that is. So they ask Pete about it. Pete, who wants to make a little puzzle out of everything, gives them a little piece of paper with the following content

> eFcMRKsT5ffkDr+PoUNLoG7*poujK34kqReFhT_m@4hTn49gbkOrlP0

He also said:

> I had to make it a little bit hard for you, because you know me too well, you know the things I like. I added a simple encryption to the code I gave you.

**Who is Pete's favourite actor?**

---

As requested, the other puzzles about Pete

- [Who is Pete's favourite composer?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70853/who-is-petes-favourite-composer)
- [Who is Pete's favourite scientist?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71055/who-is-petes-favourite-scientist)

---

I think this will be the hardest puzzle about Pete so far, I will continuously add hints to the puzzle. As always, if you find grammar errors, feel free to correct them. This time there is no special structure of the text (except the code). Good Luck

---

**Hint 1**

> There is a good chance that active puzzlers have already used the encryption Pete is talking about

**Hint 2**

> Maybe you should try to find out what Pete likes

**Hint 3**

> Less is more

**Hint 4**

> Some content may be irrelevant

Comment: Oh, my, god... PETE! Welcome back!

Comment: @PerpetualJ already thought about posting this earlier, but wasn't quite sure what would be the best idea to formulate this. The base idea was on my mind for quite some time now :D

Comment: do we need to look into any previous riddle for this?

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid I'd say this cannot hurt ;)

Comment: any more hints?

Comment: @JGibbers oh yes, sorry, I had a bit stress the last days, will update soon :)

Comment: Please link last Pete puzzles if they have anything to do with this one..

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer, work in progress...

Hint 2 says find out what Pete likes. This is no secret, he likes...

> YouTube.

I believe the content on the paper is:

> the unique identifier from one or more YouTube urls.
>  For example: *https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvCGZEqk8Ak*
>  The unique part of this url is **vvCGZEqk8Ak**

Hint 3 says "less is more"

> I believe the cipher will remove characters which will then leave a unique identifier to a YouTube video (or videos) and the answer will be contained therein.

All I need to do is figure out the "simple cipher". Any suggestions?

> If I am right it cannot be a *substition* cipher because there seem to be too many characters as it is. I am expecting a cipher that *removes* characters.

I have also noted that:

> The message contains the symbols +, * and @. I am thinking that these may separate three different identifiers, but I have tried pasting them into YouTube as they are and they are not recognised. Alternatively, I wonder if the symbols will mean something when we know what the videos are? For example if the videos contain numbers the + and * could be mathematic operators that lead to an answer?

Comment: This answer contains wrong, but also correct interpretations/explanations. Well done so far +1